# How can I import an HTML file within my HTML file?

Tags: html, tomcat, import, include, ssi

How can I import an HTML file within my HTML file? I will prepare header.html and footer.html files separately and every file that I want to include them I want to import them into my HTML file.,

**EDIT:** I see that solution based on SSI technique. I use Ubuntu and Tomcat 7.0.11. How can I enable SSI at tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem. You can write simple JavaScript code to include parts of your page on load, you can enable [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) on your web-server, and finally you can use any server-side language to dynamically include chunks of any page for output. Your choice  depends on how dynamic your web-site is.

Comment: I have an HTML file that has a navigation bar. I will cut that navigation code and put it into another file. I just want to import that HTML file from my original HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

You can include html files using frames or iframes. If you're using a server side language such as PHP or ASP you can do this without frames using *includes*.

Comment: In that case using frames is your easiest option or take a look at SSI (Server Side Includes). See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/ssi.html

Comment: Is there a good tutorial about Tomcat 7. I follow the suggestions of -how to document ssi tomcat- however there is not a server directory at my computer and couldn't enable ssi on my tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to strictly use HTML (and assuming you are using JS too) I would do the following:

You could have a `<div>` for the header, I will call it `<div id="header">`.
Using jQuery we could say something like: `$('#header').load(---html file---);`.  Aside from the pain it might be to include the JS file in all pages, it will allow you to make changes to the header globally throughout your application.