# How to include .htm file in .htm file (html)

Tags: html, import, include

i have 3 files:

`a.htm`
main page

`b.htm`
includes CSS or JS code

`c.htm`
includes a table

how can i import b.htm & c.htm into a.htm so that i could use the view the table and use the CSS or JS?
the idea is to use the same layout on multiple layouts.

Comment: Using *pure* HTML? Not much to do there. Do you have any server-side language you can use?

Comment: HTML doesn't really have an "import" feature. You can use an `iframe`, but iframes limit what you can do with the stuff in the frame, and is generally bad practice anyway. The way most people handle having a "main" or "master" page and then parts of pages is via server side scripting. They use PHP, Javascript, Python, or something else to concatenate the two files together.

Comment: could you explain a bit about iframe?
also i know i can use masterpage but im havin some problems with it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code properly I think that you've two options.

The first one is ìf you don't want to use a server-side language:

CSS : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

JS : `<script type="text/javascript">`

HTML : Just put your table into the main html (the one where you want to include this file) If your table is not fed by Datas using PHP/SQL I don't think that would be relevant to seperate it.

The other option is to use PHP so you can include views in your code. And if you want to go further and create/use some interesting fonctions you should do it using MVC.

Comment: If you really don't want to change anything and do it your way, you should check this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103793/how-can-i-import-an-html-file-within-my-html-file?rq=1) and as @Aeolingamenfel said go check how frames work on W3School.